# Add control at runtime on TAB key press

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

How can I add control on runtime - automatically add textbox and other control up to number that is needed by pressing TAB control?

Example I have to add 3 textbox - lname, lfname, ladd

then at 3rd textbox after pressing tab automatically 3textbox creates beneath them?

Comment: hello, welcome to stackoverflow, this is a free community where people answer question altruistically. For this reason, its always welcome to see a little effort from the question creator, show us What have you tried and where exactly you found problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add some Control e.g. `TextBox` use `KeyDown` event on your `Form`:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
Dim c As Integer = 0
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
    Dim txtRun As New TextBox()
    txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic" & System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(c),c - 1)
    'name
    txtRun.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 18 + (20 * c))
    ' Location of new control
    txtRun.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 25)
    ' size
    Me.Controls.Add(txtRun)
End If
End Sub
```

In case that I haven't answered your question please provide more information so I can answer more precisely.